# combining paperTeX and newspaper with a5paper

Tags: incompatibility, paper-size, newspaper

If you mix paperTeX and newspaper with a5paper layout paperTeX scales bad and newspaper uses absolute cordinates so half of the paper is not shown.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.